# How can I have my navigation menu fill the browser window without gaps on ends?

Tags: css, css-float, navigationbar

I'm using floats and trying to keep each one of three buttons in a navigation menu to ~33.3% so that it fills the screen and doesn't break when the window size shrinks, nor should it leave gaps on the ends when the browser window gets wider.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxd1vdcj/1/

```
<div id ="nav">
    <ul>
        <li id="dawn" >Tradition</li>
        <li id="dusk" >Styles</li>
        <li id="night">Contact</li>

    </ul>
</div>

#nav ul li{
    display:block;
    //width:19.3%;
    width: 33%;
    line-height: 3em;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#333), to(#111));
    color: #b0c4ff;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 140px;
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: `<a>` is not a valid `<ul>` children

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Ok thanks, I tried that with no luck.  Also your fiddle breaks when the window is small.  The `contact` button begins a new line, which isn't good.

Comment: @Squirrl try this - http://jsfiddle.net/yLzu13x1/

Comment: @MaryMelody You're the best.  That's the 2nd time you've saved me.

Comment: @Squirrl it was just a comment, not a solution :)

Comment: @Squirrl Yeah! you should accept Roko C. Buljan's answer that I gave a +1 and your question too. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, `<a>` is not a valid `<ul>` children.

100/3 = 33.333.. but you used `33%` which on larger screen sizes encounted for the 1px (up to 6px) for your three LI widths, than once you resized your page, the remaining availiable width % was not enough to contain the fixed (1px) border width, leading to a LI breaking beneath to the nearest available space.

### using `box-sizing`

Some `box-sizing` will fix your issue of borders adding up the available space.

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;} /* Global reset (also to remove 8px margin from Body) */

#nav ul{
    display:block;
    margin:10px;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
#nav ul li{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border: 1px solid black;

    display:block;
    float:left;
    width: 33%;
    line-height: 3em;
    text-align:center;
    color: #b0c4ff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xxd1vdcj/5/
Now you can even go using `33.333%` for your `LI` width.

---

### using `display:table` and `table-layout`

Since `box-sizing` is **not supported** by older browsers you can go and use this simple solution:

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#nav{
    margin:10px;
    margin-top: 140px;
}
#nav ul{
    display:table;       /* Table!! yey */
    width:100%;   
    table-layout: fixed; /* To fix LI widths */
}
#nav ul li{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: table-cell; /* Note */
    line-height: 3em;
    text-align:center;
    color: #b0c4ff;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

which excels at what `table`s are born for!

http://jsfiddle.net/xxd1vdcj/7/